# Ordering several tables in the same file using awk

Tags: awk

In my workflow, files containing simple tables with a two-line header (see end of post) are created. I want to order these tables by number using:

```
(head -n 2 && tail -n +3 | sort -n -r) > ordered.txt
```

That works fine, but I don't know how to split the file so that I can order every table and print it in ONE file. My approach is:

```
awk '/^TARGET/ {(head -n 2 && tail -n +3 | sort -n -r) >> ordered.txt}' output.txt
```

However, this causes an error message. I want to avoid any intermediate output files. What is missing in my awk command?

The input files look like that:

```
TARGET  1
Sample1 Sample2 Sample3 Pattern
3   3   3   z..........................Z........................................z.........Z...z
147 171 49  Z..........................Z........................................Z.........Z...Z
27  28  13  z..........................Z........................................z.........z...z
75  64  32  Z..........................Z........................................Z.........z...Z

TARGET  2
Sample1 Sample2 Sample3 Pattern
2   0   1   z..........................z........................................z.........Z...Z
21  21  7   z..........................Z........................................Z.........Z...Z
1   0   0   ...........................Z........................................Z.............Z
4   8   6   Z..........................Z........................................z.........Z...z
2   0   1   Z..........................Z........................................Z.........Z....
1   0   0   z..........................Z........................................Z.............Z
1   0   0   z...................................................................Z.........Z...Z

TARGET  3
Sample1 Sample2 Sample3 Pattern
1   0   0   z..........................Z........................................z.............z
1   3   0   z..........................z........................................Z.........Z...Z
1   1   0   Z..........................Z........................................Z.............z
1   0   0   Z..........................Z........................................Z.............Z
0   1   2   ...........................Z........................................Z.........Z...Z
0   0   1   z..........................z........................................z..............
```

My output should like that - no dropping of any line:

```
    TARGET  1
Sample1 Sample2 Sample3 Pattern
147 171 49  Z..........................Z........................................Z.........Z...Z
75  64  32  Z..........................Z........................................Z.........z...Z
27  28  13  z..........................Z........................................z.........z...z
3   3   3   z..........................Z........................................z.........Z...z

TARGET  2
Sample1 Sample2 Sample3 Pattern
21  21  7   z..........................Z........................................Z.........Z...Z
4   8   6   Z..........................Z........................................z.........Z...z
2   0   1   z..........................z........................................z.........Z...Z
2   0   1   z..........................z........................................z.........Z...Z
1   0   0   ...........................Z........................................Z.............Z
1   0   0   ...........................Z........................................Z.............Z
1   0   0   ...........................Z........................................Z.............Z

TARGET  3
Sample1 Sample2 Sample3 Pattern
1   0   0   z..........................Z........................................z.............z
1   0   0   z..........................Z........................................z.............z
1   0   0   z..........................Z........................................z.............z
1   0   0   z..........................Z........................................z.............z
0   1   2   ...........................Z........................................Z.........Z...Z
0   0   1   z..........................z........................................z..............
```

Comment: It is unclear what the output should be.

Comment: The output should look like the one of glenn jackman, just with a descending order of the numbers.

Comment: So you want half of table 2 to disappear ?

Comment: What is missing from your awk command is the awk language. awk is not shell, just like C is not shell. It's a completely separate tool with it's own language. I'm with @Jidder - I've  no idea what your output should be, please post it with an explanation to clarify.

Comment: No, I don't want any line to disappear. I have just noticed that this is the case with glenn's code. Thank's for that hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

requires GNU awk for the [array traversal sorting](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html):

```
gawk '
    BEGIN {PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_asc"} 
    function output_table() {
        for (key in table) print table[key]
        delete table
        i=0
    }
    /TARGET/ {print; getline; print; next} 
    /^$/ {output_table(); print; next} 
    {table[++i] = $0} 
    END {output_table()}
' file
```

outputs

```
TARGET  1
Sample1 Sample2 Sample3 Pattern
3   3   3   z..........................Z........................................z.........Z...z
27  28  13  z..........................Z........................................z.........z...z
75  64  32  Z..........................Z........................................Z.........z...Z
147 171 49  Z..........................Z........................................Z.........Z...Z

TARGET  2
Sample1 Sample2 Sample3 Pattern
1   0   0   ...........................Z........................................Z.............Z
1   0   0   z...................................................................Z.........Z...Z
1   0   0   z..........................Z........................................Z.............Z
2   0   1   Z..........................Z........................................Z.........Z....
2   0   1   z..........................z........................................z.........Z...Z
4   8   6   Z..........................Z........................................z.........Z...z
21  21  7   z..........................Z........................................Z.........Z...Z

TARGET  3
Sample1 Sample2 Sample3 Pattern
0   0   1   z..........................z........................................z..............
0   1   2   ...........................Z........................................Z.........Z...Z
1   0   0   Z..........................Z........................................Z.............Z
1   0   0   z..........................Z........................................z.............z
1   1   0   Z..........................Z........................................Z.............z
1   3   0   z..........................z........................................Z.........Z...Z
```

Comment: Works perfectly - I have just difficulties in understanding these two lines:  {table[$1,$2,$3] = $0}  & END {output_table()}. Why do you use GAWK? Is it faster?

Comment: First, I use gawk because I use a GNU system and gawk is the default awk. However, gawk implements the array traversal sorting functions, so it's required for this answer.

Comment: This line `{table[$1,$2,$3] = $0}` stores the "table" lines in an array. The array key is the first 3 columns joined with the `SUBSEP` awk variable. This allows the numeric sorting you were after. The `END {output_table()}` will print the 3rd table. It's needed because there may not be blank line at the end of the file.

Comment: Are half the records supposed to disappear ?

Comment: Oh wow - now I realize: some lines were skipped, when the first 3 columns are equal. I want to keep them all, because the patterns are all different.

Comment: Ack. Quite right. Answer is updated. Only minor changes were required

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a mess but assuming you dont want to lose records when you sort this should work

```
 awk 'function sortit(){
           x=asort(a)
           for(i=1;i<=x;i++)print b[a[i]" "d[i]++]
           delete(a);delete(b);delete(c);delete(d)
     }                             
     /^[0-9]/{a[$0]=$1;b[$1" "c[$1]++]=$0}
     /TARGET/{print;getline;print}
     !NF{sortit();print}
     END(sortit()}' file
```

Comment: You're right: I don't want to skip any lines. So your code does the job. You have just a typo in your code: using a parenthesis instead of a curly bracket after "END". Thanks for sharing that code!

Comment: However - it does not work with all input files. Lines that begin with "0 0 1 x..." are dropped - as in my modified input file!